# Excel - MDX query to SSAS Cube with cell values as parameters

Tags: excel, parameters, ssas, mdx

I am trying to get an MDX query to be executed through Excel, using cell values as parameter values.  Is there any help with this query please?

```
WITH MEMBER
[Measures].[SubDrillDown] AS [Statement Financial Analysis].[Report      Framework].PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME
SELECT NON EMPTY {
[Measures].[SubDrillDown],
[Measures].[Budget Opening],
[Measures].[Budget Closing], 
[Measures].[Actuals Opening],
[Measures].[Actuals Closing],
[Measures].[Budget],
[Measures].[Actuals],
[Measures].[Commitments Closing],
[Measures].[Job Budget],
[Measures].[Job Budget Closing],
[Measures].[Job Annual Plan],
[Measures].[Job Annual Plan Closing],
[Measures].[Job Commitments]

} ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { 
(
[Statement Financial Analysis].[Report Framework].[Group Code].ALLMEMBERS *
[Financial Periods].[Financial Periods].[Financial Period].ALLMEMBERS 
*[Financial Periods].[Financial Period Name].[Financial Period Name].MEMBERS
*[Journal Transaction Structure].[Journal Code].MEMBERS
) 
} ON ROWS 
FROM ( SELECT ({'"&c1&"'})  ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ({'"&c3&"'})  ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ({'"&c4&"'})  ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ({'"&c5&"'})  ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Fin] ))))
```

The query has been written previously and I am replacing

```
FROM ( SELECT STRTOMEMBER(@prmYear)  ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT STRTOMEMBER(@prmDept)  ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT STRTOSET(@prmEntity)  ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT STRTOSET(@prmActivity)  ON COLUMNS
```

Obviously, C1,C3,C4 and C5 are cell references on sheet1.Each of these cells has a full MDX value in, forexample:

c1 is =CONCATENATE("[Financial Periods].[Financial Periods].[Financial Period].&[",VLOOKUP(B1,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE),"-",C2,"-01 T00:00:00]")

which displays as [Financial Periods].[Financial Periods].[Financial Period].&[2005-01-01 T00:00:00], hopefully the MDX would interpret the final value

I am getting an error "Details: "AnalysisServices: Query (30, 15) The  function expects a tuple set expression for the 1 argument. A string or numeric expression was used."" and am stumped tbh.  Any help would be appreciated.

I have ran the expression with the FULL TEXT values in and works as planned, its just the referencing of the cell that is not working.

Thankyou.

Comment: You have to use the macros to pass a parameter directly to the query: https://gqbi.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/excel-user-input-for-custom-mdx-query-using-vba-and-pivots/

Comment: @DanyloKorostil why can't the user use excel's cubefunctions to construct a dynamic mdx environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an ideal answer as it is simply a link but I found the following walkthrough really informative about the power of Excel's cube functions:

https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NewZealand/2013/DBI304

Using the techniques he outlines you can deconstruct your mdx and make values in cells parameters for the mdx

Comment: @DanyloKorostil well it is quite a different approach - you need to extract sets and members and add them to different cells in the worksheet - then sort of rebuild your mdx script using what is now pseudo-embedded in the worksheet. Worth having a play as quite good fun.

Comment: Thankyou @whytheq, previously I had passed this video over as its an hour long - but it turns out that there is some good stuff in it!  Thankyou for the prompt.